# Does IBM Watson use machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, chat-bots, watson

I was reading an article on [Medium](https://chatbotsjournal.com/why-i-should-should-not-invest-in-chatbot-df952cbabf10) and wanted to make it clear whether a bot created on IBM Watson is an intelligent one or unintelligent.

> Simply put, there are 2 types of chatbots — unintelligent ones that act using predefined conversation flows (algorithms) written by developers building them and intelligent ones that use machine learning to interact with users.

Comment: I take exception to their use of intelligence, which, in AI terms, is a relative measure of problem solving strength.  If their meaning is that heuristic methods have less utility, that seems sound, but implying that ML is not algorithmic is wildly inaccurate.  Still in all, a good question about Watson!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it does and at many parts of the solution. For one of the core components - intent detection - Intento did [a benchmark comparing IBM Watson and other similar products](https://www.slideshare.net/KonstantinSavenkov/nlu-intent-detection-benchmark-by-intento-august-2017).

Outside of intent detection, there are other areas where AI techniques help - e.g. disambiguation, bootstrapping a bot from chat logs etc. Specifically for IBM Watson, you can learn more [here](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/watson-assistant/features/).

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at the [IBM Watson wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson_(computer)) reveals that it does indeed use machine learning. Watson is a complex computing system that uses a variety of cutting edge techniques and concepts such as natural language processing and machine learning.